# Requesting data from a website isn't working/loading python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
print(r.text)
```

I am trying to use this api, but it either isn't working or isn't loading. I get no errors, the IDLE just stands blank.

My requests module is up to date and I am using python 3.5.2

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or not, but If I am please guide me.

[EDIT] I've tried multiple endpoints and they all do  the same thing. This same method works perfectly for other websites in no time at all. I'm stumped.

[EDIT 2] I left it running for about 10 minutes and finally got an error:

```
 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)
```

[EDIT 3] Fixed, I did this in terminal:

```
pip install requests[security]
```

Comment: Could you paste any error messages you got? I an able to run your code on my system without any difficulties.

Comment: @rlee827 I got no error messages, it just stands loading, I have no problems trying this with other websites.

Comment: Could you try writing `r.text` into a file instead of printing it?

Comment: @rlee827 Same thing happens, I assume this means the program isn't retrieving the data from the website at all?

Comment: Does it hang after `r=requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api')` or on `print(r.text)`?

Comment: `r=requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api')` @rlee827

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: @tdelaney Indeed, I have no proxy on and my internet speed is fine, so i'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: if you don't mind wild guesses.... The site has a "contact us" link. I think it would be worth bringing it up with them. Maybe you got banned for some strange reason. Other question, though.... those other sites, were they `https`? It could be a certificate problem.

Comment: I will try to contact them, but other https and http sites worked fine @tdelaney thanks

Comment: Interesting fix. I read around a bit and `requests[security]` installs openssl which can be more secure than platform defaults (apparently, a problem with OSX from threads I read).

Comment: Its okay to answer  and accept your own question when you figure things out yourself. This will be useful information for others.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for your help

Comment: Didn't work with Python 2.7.8 on Windows for me.

Answer (score -1):

You could use: `requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api/', verify=False)`

But it seems you figured something else out.